# Tracking tasks across all Jira projects

Tags: jira

I have many projects that are in progress in JIRA with Scrum teams from User Experience (UX) and Development (dev). Is there a way to see all dev or UX tasks across all projects? I'm currently having to go into each project to view these tasks but I want view everything in one place. Is this possible?

Comment: The question, as it stands, might have several correct answers - Jira Dashboard and Jira Structures are the ones that are likely to be on the top... but there are other plugins such as [Jira Portfolio](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiraportfoliocloud/portfolio-for-jira-home-715263250.html).

Answer (score 3):

## You can create a Jira Dashboard

I used to keep a Dashboard with the Sprint Health Gadget for each of the project. This way I can see the summary status of all the projects in the Dashboard in one place. When I see something in the summary that warrants attention, I can always drill-down into that project to see the details.

Trying to see **all the tasks** from different projects in one place will be overwhelming and confusing.

However, if that is what you want, see the [High-priority issues example in this link](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/11/7-steps-to-a-beautiful-and-useful-agile-dashboard/). He has used the Filter Results gadget and filtered the tasks to see only the high priority issues. Here is the JQL:

> sprint in (openSprints(), futureSprints()) AND project in (TIS) AND
>   (Flagged is not EMPTY OR priority = Blocker)

If you add your projects and remove the filters in the JQL, you should see all the issues in one place.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclosure:** I work for the company that makes the Structure add-on for JIRA.

If you have self-hosted JIRA you can install the [Structure add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.almworks.jira.structure/server/overview) which will allow you to pull issues from different projects into one place, group, sort and filter them, view issuelink and Agile relations in a hierarchical tree, show aggregate progress, time, story points and other numerical values.

Grouping by fields such as release, sprint and assignee you will be able to track progress from as low as sub-task level across multiple projects/sprints/releases.